Test flutter state restoration in Linux
I am new to flutter, and trying to develop a simple app that needs to store some values even if killed.  I followed some examples of state restoration usage, but cannot figure out how to test in with Visual Studio in my local machine (Ubuntu OS).
Here is the code I am using for testing:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const RootRestorationScope(
    restorationId: 'root',
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Restorable Counter',
      restorationScopeId: 'application',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with RestorationMixin<MyHomePage> {
  final RestorableInt _counter = RestorableInt(0);

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter.value++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text('Restorable Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '${_counter.value}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  String? get restorationId => 'counter_page';

  @override
  void restoreState(RestorationBucket? oldBucket, bool initialRestore) {
    registerForRestoration(_counter, 'counter');
  }
}

I am using the debugging button in visual studio:

Is there any way to imitate mobile behavior in order to test state restoration in Ubuntu?
